# How to convert the output of a trained NER model to Spacy?

Tags: format, visualization, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I want to visualize and color the NEs in the text, Spacy provides this methods but I need to convert my NER output to Spacy format.

Do you know how to do that?

This is my output:

```
[

{'entity': 'LABEL_0', 'score': 0.9899187, 'index': 1, 'word': 'جاء', 'start': 0, 'end': 3}, 

{'entity': 'LABEL_2', 'score': 0.93156606, 'index': 2, 'word': 'مريم', 'start': 4, 'end': 8}, 

{'entity': 'LABEL_0', 'score': 0.95939595, 'index': 3, 'word': 'المخ', 'start': 9, 'end': 13}, 

{'entity': 'LABEL_0', 'score': 0.93106014, 'index': 4, 'word': '##اض', 'start': 13, 'end': 15}, 

{'entity': 'LABEL_0', 'score': 0.9786557, 'index': 5, 'word': 'إلى', 'start': 16, 'end': 19}, 

{'entity': 'LABEL_4', 'score': 0.8128485, 'index': 6, 'word': 'جذ', 'start': 20, 'end': 22}, 

{'entity': 'LABEL_4', 'score': 0.5465944, 'index': 7, 'word': '##ع', 'start': 22, 'end': 23}, 

{'entity': 'LABEL_6', 'score': 0.6041712, 'index': 8, 'word': 'النخلة', 'start': 24, 'end': 30}

]
```

Here is the mapping:

```
LABEL_0 -> O
LABEL_1 -> B-Num
LABEL_2 -> B-Per
LABEL_3 -> I-Per
LABEL_4 -> B-Loc
LABEL_5 -> I-Num
LABEL_6 -> I-Loc
```

I want the output to be something like this:
[image]